# How do I get rid of bogus "missing reference" errors for project's own classes in WPF?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2008

I create a custom value converter or whatever, put it in XAML, and it all compiles and runs fine, but Visual Studio keeps showing bogus

```
The type 'local:PortValidationRule' was not found. Verify that you are not
missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.
```

errors. They're an eyesore and spam up the error list and tend to mess up the visual editor. How do I get rid of them?

I'm running Visual Studio 2008 Standard SP1.

Comment: Did you try to restart VS?

Comment: I've had this problem ever since I started working with WPF four years ago. I just got fed up with it *now*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prevent this, the only option is to have the `PortValidationRule` class defined in a different assembly than your XAML file using it.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it's down to, essentially, in what order does the compiler do it's business, something you have no control over. The fact studio complains is really just an indication you might want to split your stuff up since it's self-referential.